# Python 3.11 Django: variable from views.py not displaying in index.html

Tags: python-3.x, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a project and I want to display the date on the webpage.

Here is the function in my views.py

```
def date(request):
    template = loader.get_template('app/index.html')

    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    format_date = current_date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
    context = {'date': format_date}

    # log format_date
    logger.info(format_date)

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Here is the relevant html from index.html

```
<!-- templates/home.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}

<!-- Date -->
{% block date %}
  <p class="datedisplay">Today is {{ date }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the relevant html from base.html

```
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    {% block header %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block date %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>

  <main>
    <section class="login">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </section>

    <section class="bio">
      {% block brief %}
      {% endblock %}
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Here are the URL Patterns from app/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', views.date, name='date')
]
```

I have set up logging and can confirm that the formatted date is being return properly.

I have tried at least 6 sources on how to display a variable from views.py to the webpage. I am not certain whether I need to be messing with the urls if I am not trying to redirect my user to another page. All I want is for the date to be a variable that displays when the web page is opened. Nevertheless I have attempted editing the urls.py related to my /app/index.html.

I have suspicions that the issues are with the redirection between index.html and base.html. In index.html I am setting up the actual text and base.html is used to arrange it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the date attribute in models.py. Do something like this:

```
# models.py
import datetime
class Date(models.Model):
  display_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
  @property
  def display_date_string(self):
    return self.display_date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")

# views.py
from .models import *
def relevant_site(request):
  date = Date.objects.all()
  context = {'date': date}
  return render(request, relevant_site.html, context)

<!--relevant_site.html-->
{{ date.display_date_string }}
```

Until you define it in your models, your views will be unable to execute it.